# Use the same topic as a source more than once with Kafka Streams DSL

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Is there a way to use the same topic as the source for two different processing routines, when using Kafka Streams DSL?

```
StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilder();

// use the topic as a stream
streamsBuilder.stream("topic")...

// use the same topic as a source for KTable
streamsBuilder.table("topic")...

return streamsBuilder.build();
```

Naive implementation from above throws a `TopologyException` at runtime: *Invalid topology: Topic topic has already been registered by another source.* Which is totally valid, if we dive into underlying Processor API. Is using it the only way out?

**UPDATE:**
The closest alternative I've found so far:

```
StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilder();

final KStream<Object, Object> stream = streamsBuilder.stream("topic");

// use the topic as a stream
stream...

// create a KTable from the KStream
stream.groupByKey().reduce((oldValue, newValue) -> newValue)...

return streamsBuilder.build();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the same topic as stream and as table is semantically questionable IMHO. Streams model immutable facts, while changelog topic that you would use to read into a KTable model updates.

If you want to use a single topic in multiple streams, you can reuse the same `KStream` object multiple times (it's semantically like a broadcast):

```java
KStream stream = ...
stream.filter();
stream.map();
```

Also compare: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6687 (there are plans to remove this restriction. I doubt, we will allow to use one topic as `KStream` and `KTable` at the same time though—compare my comment from above).

Comment: Thanks, Matthias! I understand the semantics difference behind the two, I just hoped to use some mildly dirty tricks to make it work the way I described.

The JIRA issue you referred to is actually the addition to an answer to what I've been looking for: such tricks are not welcome, but feasibility of them might be introduced later in time. I'm going to accept that as an answer, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

yes, you can, but for that you need to have multiple `StreamsBuilder`

```
StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder1 = new StreamsBuilder();
streamsBuilder1.stream("topic");

StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder2 = new StreamsBuilder();
streamsBuilder2.table("topic");

Topology topology1 = streamsBuilder1.build();
Topology topology2 = streamsBuilder2.build();

KafkaStreams kafkaStreams1 = new KafkaStreams(topology1, streamsConfig1);
KafkaStreams kafkaStreams2 = new KafkaStreams(topology2, streamsConfig2);
```

Also make sure that you have different `application.id` values for each of `StreamsConfig`

Comment: Sure, that's one work around, but I was wondering if that is possible within the same `Topology` (for my own reasons: supporting one `KafkaStreams` object in the application is much easier in our case).

I mean, it is possible through Processor API, right.

Comment: ok, if you could create `KTable` from `KStream`, then you could also try the following: `KStream<Object, Object> kStream = streamsBuilder.stream("topic");
        kStream.foreach(...); // process KStream;
        KTable kTable = kStream.groupByKey().reduce(...);`

Comment: Thanks, Vasiliy, must've missed your comment back in the days, sorry! As you can see, I've had the same solution (see updated section), so I believe this is the only way at the moment, unfortunately not the one I've looked for. It's OK then, we can live with that, right?

Comment: right, it's ok to use streams as you posted in update

Comment: @VasiliySarzhynskyi your solution would have been attractive IMO if it were not  for the fact that you lose data locality across topologies. i.e., if there are multiple consumer instances, the partitions end up in different JVMs. Thoughts?

Comment: @senseiwu what is wrong with the fact that messages from different partitions will be handled on diff JVMs? what are the drawbacks with this?

Comment: it depends on the usecase. For my usecase, it is a no go because I am using one stream to build an in memory secondary time series index which would be used by the other one. If keys across topologies do not end up with same instance, then it is worthless