# How to implement Kafka Streams topology that process single topic with interactive queries store and global store

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to implement Kafka Streams that is going to treat single topic stream as global database with interactive queries possible. So I want to have:

1. global store for records (GlobalKTable, KeyValueStore)
2. queryable store, that allows me to get result of an interactive query (maximum)

Interactive query has to calculate the global maximum of one of record's field:

```
 KStream<String, TercUnitRecord> recordsStream = topologyBuilder.stream(topicName);
 KTable<String, Long> lastUpdateStore = recordsStream.mapValues(record -> record.getLastUpdate())
                .selectKey((key, value) -> "lastdate")
                .groupByKey(Grouped.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long()))
                .reduce((maxValue, currValue) -> maxValue.compareTo(currValue) == 1 ? maxValue : currValue,
 Materialized.as("terc-lastupdate"));
```

However, I am facing problem that I cannot use the same single topic as source in one Kafka Streams instance. I have done a reasearch and the only way I found to do this is by multiple KafkaStreams instances, but I am not sure it is the correct and only way to achieve this. Any ideas?

Comment: `.stream(topicName)` is using "single topic", but multiple topics are created behind the scenes, if thats what you mean?

Comment: Actually, multiple stores, to be more precise. I don't want to create new topic, I want to have internal store to which stream is processed to get what I want (maximum).

Comment: Can you point at the research that says you need multiple instances?

Comment: @OneCricketeer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52426744/use-the-same-topic-as-a-source-more-than-once-with-kafka-streams-dsl

Comment: If your input topic has multiple partitions, you will need to use a repartition topic to get all data into a single partition -- otherwise, you cannot compute a global maximum. Also note, that a "global store" is for "broadcasting state" -- it does not really seems to apply to your use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used multiple KafkaStreams instances for each task and it worked properly.